# Is there a static analyzer can check local variables re-assignment in C/C++/Objective-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, constants, local-variables

Is there any way (such as compiler flag) to set *ALL* local variables `const` automatically without the specifier in C/C++/Objective-C? Just like `let` semantics in functional languages.

Because I want to set `const` to all local variables, but it's too annoying and makes code less readable. If I can set all local variables `const` by default, and I can set some variables `mutable` manually, it would be great for me. But I never heard about it.

If you know something please let me know.

---

Edit

I thought a little more about this after reading responses. And I strongly agree to it would disrupt strong C convention (or standard?) because it's already defined as mutable by default.

So my idea is becoming into another form. Kind of static analyzer. Not compiler. 
if some tool can check reassigned local variables, and can define any mechanism marking mutable variable (for example, a specific empty preprocessor symbol), it would be perfect tool for me. And also, it won't disrupt C conventions.

So I changed question title a little and added this text.

Comment: Do you have an example of your coding style? I find that well-factored code doesn't often need a huge amount of constant local variables around...

Comment: Out of curiosity - why would you need that? What do you win? Also, I don't see how this makes the code more readable, hiding the `const`.

Comment: Wouldn't this give you trouble with a lot of stuff, like loop counters for instance?

Comment: Imagine all the fun an occasional reader would have looking at your program :)

Comment: "Because I want to set const to all local variables, but it's too annoying and makes code less readable." - It may be annoying. But, how does it make the code less readable? It appears that code will be more readable when you add explicit "const" key word.

Comment: @Eonil - That's likely how the language *would* have been designed if starting from scratch now, const by default and mutable/var when explicitly asked for. But that didn't happen, so the answer is - no, no compiler I know supports that.

Comment: I sympathies with you. I've toyed with similar ideas myself (I wanted readonly ivars in Objective-C. i.e. set in `init` only). I approach mutable state with extreme prejudice. However, I reached the conclusion that despite the benefits of the immutable state, it is simply not idiomatic in C/Objective-C and therefore doesn't help with readability.

Comment: @KerrekSB My intention is just decreasing human error. By making all variables immutable by default, but mutable for limited context. Because I make a lot mistake on code which becomes bug :( so I wanted a tool protect my code from my mistake. Maybe static analyzer can check reassigned variable would be a good substitute.

Comment: @KirilKirov Ah yeah I agree. I couldn't thought about it. C is already solid language. My idea will disrupt strong convention.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck I think this can be solved by marking some variables explicitly mutable.

Comment: I edited my question. Thanks for all valuable opinions!

Comment: "it's…makes code less readable" -- programmers and tools understand the `const` keyword and semantics better than some intermediate representation you think of (without creating a new language). for example, it's rare that a `const` `typedef` is a practical alternative which is more readable than just using the `const` keyword. i prefer that Bo's suggestion were used. however, it's usually easiest to get the semantics of `const` by typing `const`. sure, you could typedef everything, everywhere to suppose explicit mutability -- but i've found that approach less readable than using many `const`s

Comment: By not declaring local variables as const, you have to run a separate tool. Isn't that more annoying than explicitly writing "const" and letting the compiler check it?

Comment: @zvrba Running tool as part of build process is automatic and nothing annoying. Anyway even I put `const ` on all variables, I can omit some by mistake. I think that's the benefit of this tool can make it sure.

Answer (score 1):

... errr sort of by employing macros:

```
int main () {

 #define int const int
 #define float const float

 int x = 5;
 float y = 5.3;

 #undef int
 #undef float

 return 0;
}
```

you can even separate these def's and undef's into two different headers, so that your code would look a bit cleaner:

```
int main () {

 #include "all_vars_const_begin.h"

 int x = 5;
 float y = 5.3;

 #include "all_vars_const_end.h"

 return 0;
}
```

But i'm not sure if this style is Ok.

Comment: that will also add constness to any functions you call between those macros, so that's probably a bad idea.

Comment: Agree. If possible - function calls must be moved out of this macro scope. Or such functions must begin with `#include "all_vars_const_end.h"`- which makes a lot of code clutter of course.

Comment: Good idea, except this is not automatic.